# Is 'examples' a default output variable for HuggingFace transformers library?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering

I'm running various example code from HuggingFace docs, and a variable `examples` repeatedly appears in these tutorials.
Many functions have it as a formal parameter:

```
def preprocess_function(examples):
    questions = [q.strip() for q in examples["question"]]
    ....
```

Yet when these functions are called, no input is passed in:

`tokenized_squad = squad.map(preprocess_function, batched=True, ....)`

This example from the [Question Answering tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.31.0/en/tasks/question_answering#load-squad-dataset).

What exactly is `examples`, and why doesn't it need to be passed in when the function is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you understand, we first have to clarify that `map` does not have the called function `preprocess_function()` as an argument but the function itself `preprocess_function`. So basically what map does is:

1. For a given dataset (here `squad`)
2. Execute a function `preprocess_function`
3. On every batch (batched=True with a default batch size of 1000)

So what this means is that `map` will process the whole dataset `squad` in chunks (batches) of 1000 items at a time. So for every batch (a sublist of examples from the dataset) the function is called. Very simplified, under the hood, map does something like this:

1. Chop `squad` in sublists (batches of 1000 examples each)
2. Process each batch, i.e. passing the examples to the function
3. Put the results of the function back into the resulting dataset.

As a reference point, it might be useful for you to read up on the built-in `map` in Python, which works similarly on iterables. It is also a concept that returns in other programming languages so it is good to know!